# How to select a dropdownlist value using webdriver and raw_input() in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, webdriver

Here's working code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='log']/option[text()='eag']").click()
```

It selects 'eag' value but I want user to choose the value using raw_input(). E.g.

```
choice = raw_input("choose: ")
```

And then use that variable to select chosen value ;)

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I understand you want to manually provide test data while test script is executing.. Am I right?

Comment: I need to parse the content of the page but first I have to select and input values ;) and I would like to do it from the console not from the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should help.

```
    choice = raw_input("choose: ")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='log']/option[text()='" + choice + "']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the better way you should use `Select()` to select an option from drop down as below :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


 element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "log")))

 select = Select(element)

 choice = raw_input("choose: ")

 select.select_by_visible_text(choice)
```

Hope it helps...:)